# Executable script code found in signature block - PowerShell Error

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've run into an error with a PowerShell script:

```
At line:365 char:17
+                 $HTMLerror += $usererror
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.

At line:367 char:17
+                 $ErrorMessage
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.

At line:371 char:1
+ $content = "
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.

At line:390 char:1
+ $table += $content
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.

At line:394 char:5
+     $HTMLerror | Add-Content C:\test.html
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.

At line:396 char:5
+     $table | Add-Content C:\test.html
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.

At line:398 char:5
+     $endtable = "</table>"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.

At line:400 char:5
+     $endtable | Add-Content C:\test.html
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
```

After doing some research, it seems to be a bug in PowerShell. The first 364 lines of code work just fine, but for some reason, this error starts at line 365. Has anybody ever discovered a workaround for this bug?

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated! - leah_cyberpadawan

P.S. this is running in VS code, PSVersion 4.0.

Comment: Is this a signed script?

Comment: @EBGreen...right now my execution policy is set to RemoteSigned.

Comment: @EBGreen...I just copied the code over to a brand new .ps1 file and now it works.  It's the exact same code, but not coming up with the "Executable script code" error. Weird ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So it sounds like it is the same environment bug that was mentioned in the articles that I imagine you read. No clear reason for it but resetting the environment seems to clear it.

Comment: Slightly annoying, but workable. Hopefully, the new version of Powershell will fix this issue.  Thanks, @EBGreen!